# Get Removed characters from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am using Regex to remove unwanted characters from string like below:

```
str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\u0020-\u007E]", "");
```

How can I retrieve distinct characters which will be removed in efficient way?

**EDIT:**

```
Sample input  : str         = "This☺ contains Åüsome æspecialæ characters"
Sample output : str         = "This contains some special characters"
                removedchar = "☺,Å,ü,æ"
```

Comment: Please post a sample input with expected output. Right now, you only remove all characters but those from space till `z`.

Comment: added sample input and output as requested by @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do it with a *callback* method inside the [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) overload with an *evaluator*:

> *evaluator*
>              Type: [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx)
>               A custom method that examines each match and returns either the original matched string or a replacement string.

C# demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static List<string> characters = new List<string>();
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = Regex.Replace("§My string 123”˝", "[^\u0020-\u007E]", Repl);//""
        Console.WriteLine(str); // => My string 123
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", characters)); // => §, ”, ˝
    }

    public static string Repl(Match m)
    {
        characters.Add(m.Value);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/nJTSsy)

In short, declare a "global" variable (a list of strings, here, `characters`), initialize it. Add the `Repl` method to handle the replacement, and when `Regex.Replace` calls that method, add each matched value to the `characters` list.

Answer (score 2):

```
string pattern = @"[\u0020-\u007E]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
List<string> matches = new List<string> ();

foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(str))
{
    if (!matches.Contains (match.Value))
    {
        matches.Add (match.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I also remove characters at the same time from above code instead of using Regex.Replace ?